# How to move labels in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, label, uilabel

[image]

Here i need to hide the phone number, email , birthDate, anniversary date and other labels in case there is no values for those fields. How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many ways, starting with the simplest:

```
self.emailLabel.hidden = YES;
```

But you probably want to reformat the other parts of the view to fit the empty space.  Keeping it simple, you would then do something like this:

```
self.phoneLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(self.phoneLabel.frame, 0, -self.emailLabel.bounds.size.height);
```

... and so on for anything below.  But you can see how this would become tedious.  The next and probably best alternative is a UITableView that adjusts it's section count based on whether some of that data is present.  That would go like this.  Prepare a mutable array of arrays with the parts of your model and their values.

```
- (void)prepareModel {

    self.model = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self.model addObject:@[@"Name", @"Judy"]; // get "Judy" from your data

    if (/* model has email */) {
        [self.model addObject:@[@"Email", @"judy@gmail.com"];  // get email from your model
    }
    // and so on for conditional parts of your model
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.model.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

    return self.model[section][0];
}
```

And the cellForRow would init the cell using `self.model[section][1]`.

Comment: Thankyou so much friend.. But can you pls give me some hint abt the UIDesign.. Can i have a similar UIDesign to the above screenshot using this method?

Comment: Yes.  Table views by default look a lot like what you've sketched.  The switches will probably need to go in a custom subclass of UITableViewcell.

Comment: what should i give for "numberOfRowsInSection" method? It depends on how many labels are there for a particular contact right.. what to give for it..

Comment: Yes. It looks like usually one, but e.g. The phone section has three.

Comment: Since the cellForRow, didselectRow methods don have a section parameter passed, i couln't use self.model[section][1] in them.. Can u help on that

Comment: NSIndexPath provides .row and .section properties.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is simply hide the `UILabel's` if the value for the `NSStrings` that you are putting them in is `NULL`/`nil` .

```
NSString *labelString;
if([labelString length]>0)
{

}
else
Label.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Yeah.. thats right.. But if i hide a particular label(say phone label) that space will be empty right. So how to move the other labels (for which there is a value) upwards.?

Comment: @ManojEllappan- you have to give dynamic heights of labels for that or you can paste the code here for this

Comment: Oh so thats your issue :P .... For that pls check @danh answer where he has mentioned self.phoneLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(self.phoneLabel.frame, 0, -self.emailLabel.bounds.size.height);

Comment: @VivekSehrawat: Sorry frnd.. I couldn't get you.. You want me to paste the code here?

Comment: @ManojEllappan- u can refer danh ans. i commented before his answer

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a better idea to use a UITableView to do this, by putting the labels in rows of the tables. If the labels are empty, you can delete the table rows and iOS will dynamically resize the table height for you.